# How to find IIS default port using command prompt?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, windows

How do I find the IIS Default Web Site's port number from the command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the IIS admin scripts installed, from a command prompt with elevated privileges:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs GET W3SVC/1/ServerBindings
```

This assumes the ID of your default web site is 1.

The output would be something like:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

ServerBindings                           : (LIST)  (1 Items)  
":80:"
```

The `":80:"` is the port IIS is listening on for the site.

If you don't have the admin scripts installed you run the IIS setup and add the option.  It's under

`IIS > Web Management Tools > IIS 6 Management Capability > IIS 6 Scripting Tools`

Using C# to find the port is off-topic here, but [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14194792/75852) on Stack Overflow should help you.